# Combinatoric system which using in bookies "S3" system

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, classification, clustering, statistics

I am interested what type of combinatorics is using for following bookmakers system called "S3":

1. We have  N={1..8} `events`
2. We build `express pairs` C=8 like

   [(1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 6), (1, 6, 8), (2, 3, 5),
    (2, 5, 8), (3, 7, 8), (4, 5, 7), (4, 6, 7)]

Each `event` repeats 3-times: 1 =>  (**1**, 2, 4), (**1**, 3, 6), (**1**, 6, 8)..

It's not `permutation`, `combination`... Please advice what is it?

I want as example generate in similar way `4 from 10` if this possible. After I'd like to predict the optimal way for building the `pairs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be interpreted as an unusual error correcting code with a non-binary signal.

Essentially, you want the tuples to be very different, i.e. there are no two tuples that agree in two positions. That is also a simple strategy for producing such codes (the more interesting question is what (x,y) combination is best.)

Think of it this way: assuming you only know part of the tuple. Say the first is unknown: (?, 2, 4) then you want to be able still conclude the correct triple.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction